# Changing textures on a Model messes up antialiasing? (XNA)

Tags: xna, 3d, models

Here is a code sample:

```
        blockModel = game.Content.Load<Model>("Models/Cubes/Cube"); //this is a .fbx file, made in blender

        absoluteBlockTransforms = new Matrix[blockModel.Bones.Count];
        blockModel.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo(absoluteBlockTransforms);

        /*
        foreach (ModelMesh mesh in blockModel.Meshes)
        {
            foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
            {
                effect.Texture = game.Content.Load<Texture2D>("Textures/Cubes/CubeLayout"); //this is the texture it's already using, but copy-pasted into a different directory
            }
        }*/
```

This looks fine[image: Good image]

Now if I uncomment the lines above, somehow everything gets screwed up?

[image: Bad image]

Somehow just setting the Texture property messes something up, but I'm not sure what exactly (aside from the symptoms).  Note that framerate doesn't actually change; the small difference is just a coincidence.  Also, the multisampling property is set *after* this is called, so it's not an issue of it somehow changing the graphics property.

Comment: Is it just me or has the lighting disappeared on the second one?

Comment: Definitely something weird going on, but that might be something added by Blender.  Lighting is disabled for these models.  I think it's more of a fade effect?

Comment: Well, I'd use it as a starting point to investigate yourself what's going wrong. It makes your question look much more professional if you can show you've done your own research.

Comment: Is it possible that you aren't generating the mipmaps for this loaded texture or that when you brought it into xna the content importer set the color space to DXT?

Comment: I don't think it's the lighting that's changed, it's the texture mipmapping. What's your actual question? What are you trying to solve?

Comment: Well, I didn't know the word mipmapping before right now, so maybe that's what's going wrong.  I just know it looks bad, and I'm not sure why, and I'd like it to stop. I'll google around a bit and see if that word is relevant.

Comment: Aha!  So the answer was, when importing through the content processor, there was a hidden option to generate MipMaps which was set to False.  I changed it to true and it works now.  Thanks to Byte56 and RobCurr for setting me on the right track; if you'd like to turn that into an answer I'd glady accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was eluded to in the comments, the problem is that in the second half your textures are missing mipmaps.

Comment: ...and Tetrad comes in for the steal :p

Comment: +1, correct answer. Though I was thinking more along the lines of too localized.